# My website is taking so much CPU on my computer

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

[image: here is my performance for 2 seconds][image: The tab that has 36% cpu usage is the tab of my website]

I'm using django with pure css and js in this project and it seems that my website is consuming so much cpu, also i'm using a gradient animation with css:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 85, 202), rgb(18, 103, 248));
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}
.nav-link,
.navbar-brand,
.nav-link:hover,
.navbar-brand:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(247, 85, 202), rgb(18, 103, 248));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  color: transparent;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

In addition i'm using an event listener to the whole document using Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.edit').forEach((button) => {
  .
  .
  .
})
document.querySelectorAll('.filter-green').forEach(like => {...})
```

Comment: This is by far not enough information to figure out if your webpage really is responsible for that and if so it is what the reason might be. Instead of using the task manager, you should use the performance tool in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: Where's the backend code? That might be contributing

Comment: @mstephen19 Why should the backend code be relevant?

Comment: The Django part is (likely) not relevant, since Django simply returns HTML pages, CSS data, etc. Once that is done, Django is no longer involved, so it is the browser that has to render it properly.

Comment: @t.niese Who knows what he's doing there. He could be using websockets ya never know

Comment: @t.niese sorry for that i'm new to web development and I didn't know there is a "performance tab in dev tool" i'll use it to detect problems

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i've used different browser it's the same problem

Comment: It's likely the css animations.

Comment: @madprops in performance log,  yes it's likely the cause... any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: No. What I do is just not use heavy animations.

Comment: If it's just a temporary short hover effect it shouldn't be a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of animation on gradient background - if just on the body element then on my system (Windows 10/Edge reasonably powerful laptop) I don't see so much CPU being utilised, but the GPU usage is very high (around 48%).

If I then bring in the animations on the other two elements which have animated backgrounds the GPU goes up to anything between 60% and 75%.

So start by deciding what really has to have an animated background. I suspect it's the body that you want to show this, and remove the animations from the other elements.

You still have high either CPU or GPU usage and your users will not thank you for such battery-flattening behavior.

I would suggest you either scrap the idea of animating this type of gradient or at minimum provide a way for your users to switch it on and off. In any case, pay attention to whether they have asked for a low-motion site - some people react badly to movement on the screen.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) for info on accessibility and animation.

Comment: thanks i'd consider  that in my projects